# Version Control for School Project

Tags: version-control

we will be doing a project for our Object Oriented Software Eng. class, and our team consists 4 people, including myself. Our groups were made random, so I do not know their level of skills. Maybe they have never heard of version control. I am looking for a system that will allow us to work together. I have used SVN and Git for a very little time. However, I am not very confident with them. Can you suggest a nice and easy to use system that is compatible with Eclipse or NetBeans IDE? Simplicity is the most important thing and I do not know how to use Git or SVN for a project more than one people. (I have only used them individually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have some kind of Source control.

If you have used SVN/GIT in your own projects using it in a team is just as easy.  SVN is easiest, however even though it is a little harder I would go for mercurial with [tortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), hosted for free at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

1. It will Integrate into the windows UI
2. Its distributed which will make things smoother and reduce merge issues
3. You get free private hosting

Answer (score 2):

You can use tortoise [SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) or [VSS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=407) (Visual source safe) to maintain project among multiple peoples. In both tool, you can maintain local copy of project in your PC and commit your changes on server when it completes.

Version control tools comparision : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software

Comment: I would say TortoiseSVN, nice and simple to use as it integrates into the Windows.  Not using source control for any project, even a school project seems daft to me, you need some kind of source control, the risk of just using dropbox is too great.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/). It is easy to use and portable (it's written in Python). If you use Windows, you will probably find [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) useful too, as it provides Explorer extensions for mostly all functions Mercurial supports. There are also many sites that provide free project hosting for this VCS, such as [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). And [here](http://hginit.com/) is a nice tutorial about Mercurial.

EDIT: I once found a Mercurial plug-in for Eclipse. You can find it by searching in *Help > Install Software* in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Dropbox as source control in a project once, it worked ok you can also revert to old version of your files which is great, we didn`t have to work in the same files so there was no conflict.

But now that I have gotten used to svn and mercurial I would never use something else. I too would recommend using mercurial with tortoiseHg and a bitbucket acount. I have started using it for smaller project as well, I simply did a repository with all of them in it so I have at least a backup and I am able to revert to an old version if need be.

My recommandation is to avoid sharing a folder using tools like dropbox and use a real source control like mercurial hosted on bitbucket (free for project with less than 4 users).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say using SVN or GIT is a bit over kill for a school project which is likely to not last that long.

Another option would be to use something like [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com).

Comment: You are right, they all seem an overkill for a school project to me, we just want concurrency between us.

Comment: DropBox would offer that, though you couldn't work on the same file, you can edit different ones and once you save the file is automatically uploaded to the server and downloaded on whoever else the account is shared with.

Comment: So we will just need to separate files to each member

Comment: -1; School is a great opportunity to learn how to use a good tool - dropbox is synchronization hell if you have too many people working at the same time.